# I need to apply a filter in powerapps to display json files (name) as lookup in other list from document library in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have few files stored in document library. Most files will be under folders.

***Eg: Folder1>A1json

                   Files Folder>F1Json

Folder2>A2Json

                   Files Folder>F2Json

Folder3>A3Json

              Files Folder>F3Json***

I need to display only json file name as lookup in other list like **(A1Json/A2Json/A3Json)**.
Need not include files that come under "**Files Folder**". Kindly help if any logical filter can solve this.

Tried these method but not receiving the required result
1.Filter(Document, 'Folder path'="Shared Documents/")
Filter(Documents, 'Folder path' = "Shared Documents/" && IsFolder = false).Title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter('Documents',(IsFolder= false && Not("Files/" in 'Full Path')),EndsWith('File name with extension',"json")).Name